# RSS authentication with Spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-mvc, rss, spring-security

My application is secured using Spring Security and authenticating to LDAP. The problem is that RSS feed must be secured too, allowing access only to registered users, but without redirecting to the login page.

Is there an standard approach for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try forcing credentials to be sent via HTTP headers (basic auth is fine over HTTPS) and disabling both form login and session cookies. Do this by setting the `create-session` attribute and putting an `http-basic` element inside it.

```
<security:http create-session="never">
    <security:http-basic />
    ...
</security:http>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that users log in using form login and session cookies. I just need this because RSS clients won't understand form login authentication.

Comment: @Sinuhe: The RSS clients *can't* use form login auth, so you have no alternative but to use something that does work. But you can configure different login methods on different paths (see the section of the Spring Security docs on the filter chain and the `DelegatingFilterProxy` class for how).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to give each user some sort of token that goes on the end of the RSS url. You can then match users to tokens, and not send the RSS response unless you get a matching token.

You could authenticate the token in a couple of different ways:

1. Plug into the spring security authentication architecture by writing an authentication provider
2. Handle the matching in the controller that outputs the RSS feed.

This isn't as secure as normal browsing with having the user log in, but it is more secure than just a naked URL that anyone can hit.